# why do python lists doesn't store data properly during recursion

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, recursion, set

I am very much confused with my following code,
The code is about printing all the possible subsets(power set) for a given set of numbers.
It works well when I use a set() for storing but it fails while using lists in the process of recursion. It returns a list of empty lists

```
def helper(self,ind,l,nums,ans,n):
    ans.append(l)
    for i in range(ind,n):
        if ind!=i and nums[i]==nums[i-1]:
            continue
        l.append(nums[i])
        self.helper(i+1,l,nums,ans,n)
        l.remove(nums[i])
def subsetsWithDup(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
    nums.sort()
    n = len(nums)
    ans = []
    self.helper(0,[],nums,ans,n)
    return ans
```

But using set it works completely fine

```
    def helper(self,ind,l,nums,ans,n):
        ans.add(tuple(l))
        for i in range(ind,n):
            if ind!=i and nums[i]==nums[i-1]:
                continue
            l.append(nums[i])
            self.helper(i+1,l,nums,ans,n)
            l.remove(nums[i])
    def subsetsWithDup(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
        nums.sort()
        n = len(nums)
        ans = set()
        self.helper(0,[],nums,ans,n)
        return ans
```

I want to know the why is it returning empty list why doesn't it store the appended lists properly

Comment: `ans.append(l)` in the `list` based solution does not clone like the `set` version, where you did `ans.add(tuple(l))`.  Try `ans.add(list(l))` or  `ans.add(l.copy())` and see if makes a difference.

Answer (score 2):

You are storing the `l` object in your `ans` list.  You then go on to manipulate the `l` list, and by the time the function is finished, `l` is empty.  So, `ans` will end up with a set of empty list objects.

In the `set` case, it works NOT because it's a set, but because you have made a copy of `l` and converted it to a tuple.  If you did the same in the list case, it also would work.